# Python 2.7 - how to count lines in files and use the results further

Tags: python, function, line-count

I have to write a script that lists all the text files in a directory, then counts the number of lines in each file and then gives you the max amount, the minimum amount and average.

so far I have this:

```
import glob
import os

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f, start = 1):
            pass
    return i

files = glob.glob("/home/seb/Learning/*.txt")
print files

length = []

for file in files:
    file_len(file)
    length.append(i)

print length
```

As you (and me) could expect it works up until

```
length.append(i)
```

because i is not identified - I thought it was worth a shot though.

My question would be, how can I use the return of the function to append it to a list?

Comment: Instead of editing the title with `[solved]` you should rather add your own answer and accept it. This will mark the question properly as "solved".

Comment: Don't add *solved* to your post; rather, you can mark an answer that helped you the most as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `file_len(file)` to a variable:

```
flength = file_len(file)
length.append(flength)
```

The name `i` is a local name in `file_len` and not visible outside of the function, but the function *does* return the value.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I realised that as soon as I posted and felt dumb ._.